# StripeInvalidRequestError: This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_payment_method

Tags: node.js, terminal, stripe-payments

i am integrating stripe terminal and i am following below steps:

step 1:

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    currency: 'usd',
    payment_method_types: ['card_present'],
    capture_method: 'manual',
    amount: 1000,
})

Response : success with status 'requires_payment_method'
```

step 2:

```
stripe.terminal.readers.processPaymentIntent({
    'reader_id',
    'payment_intent'
})

Response : success with status 'in_progress'
```

step 3:

```
stripe.terminal.readers.retrieve({'reader_id'});

Response : success with status 'in_progress'
```

step 4:

```
stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve({'payment_intent'});

Response : success with status 'requires_payment_method'
```

step 5:

```
stripe.paymentIntents.capture('{payment_intent}')

Response : error with status 'requires_payment_method'

Error : 'This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_payment_method. Only a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses may be captured: requires_capture.',
```

following this document link : https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/collect-payment

Comment: What is happening on the reader after step 2? This should be when you are prompted to present a card and you'd use the test card to pay, before proceeding with step 3 & 4.